# Choose a Mail Merge template using a drop down - Microsoft Word

Tags: mailmerge

I want to generate documents using a selection of templates and a selection of data sets. So ideally there will be a custom drop down the user can use to select the desired template and another custom drop down where the user can select the desired data source and generate the documents. It is the user's responsibility to have the template populated in advance with the correct fields as per the selected data source.

So in summary, what I want to do is to add custom buttons, drop downs to Microsoft word (Or a custom form that can be loaded using a button on the ribbon bar) that will enable the user to load up templates to a drop down from a given directory using a file open dialog box, and to load up data sources to another drop down using a file open dialog box and then a generate button to generate documents according to the selected data source and the template.

I'm a developer but new to VBA. Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction with some sample code or a better way of doing this. The solution has to be simple enough for a non IT person to generate documents using different templates selected using a drop down.

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,
Dushan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it myself. Let me know if anybody needs help on this.